# Подключение к локальной базе данных выдаёт ошибку

Tags: c#, sql

Пытаюсь подключиться к локальной базе данных Visual Studio:

```
string conStr = @"Data Source= (LocalDB)\v12.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Mydatabase1.mdf;Integrated Security=True";
SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection(conStr);
```

Проверил значение connect при отладке, в ней ошибка: ServerVersion = '"connect.ServerVersion" выдал исключение типа "System.InvalidOperationException"

Ещё в конце выполнения программы выдаёт ошибку:
Вызвано исключение: "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException" в System.Data.dll

Если ошибка в строке подключения, то как её найти и исправить?

Вот ошибка в переменной connect:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот так пробовал просто для этих двух строчек отдельный проект создать. Вот код:

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string conStr = "Data Source = (LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB; AttachDbFilename =D:\\Projects\\TryConnectToDB\\Trydatabase1.mdf; User Instance=true; Integrated Security = True";
            SqlConnection connect1 = new SqlConnection(conStr);
            }
```

Эти две строчки пробовал писать и просто в классе Form. Результат тот же выдаёт ту же ошибку. Файл базы данных по указанному пути есть! Даже Visual Studio переустановил всё равно выдаёт туже ошибку. В чём же проблема?

Comment: текст ошибки какой?

Comment: @tym32167 Вот текст ошибки: Вызвано исключение: "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException" в System.Data.dll

Comment: это не текст, это тип ошибки и место ошибки. Должен быть ещё текст.

Comment: @tym32167 Текст ошибки не выводится. А причина по-моему кроется где-то здесь: в значении connect, при отладке в ней обнаружена ошибка: ServerVersion = '"connect.ServerVersion" выдал исключение типа "System.InvalidOperationException"

Comment: не знаю, я по той информации, что вы показали, ничего не могу сказать. Разве что убедитесь, что у вас установлена `LocalDB` на той машине, где вы код запускаете.

Comment: @tym32167 LokalDB на той же машине.

Comment: Попробуйте [использовать try-catch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PpcIf.png), может увидите текст ошибки

Comment: Ошибки не показал.

Comment: @tym32167, Если строка подключения к базе данных за пределами try то  выдаёт ошибку, а если внутри блока try ошибки нет(!). Как Вы думаете в чём причина?

Comment: Потому что конструкция try-catch ловит ошибку, потому ошибка у вас также есть, только дальше этой конструкции она не идет.

Comment: @tym32167 создал новый проект состоящий только из упомянутых двух строчек подключения к базе данных и простой локальной базы данных, выдаёт туже самую ошибку. Что можете посоветовать?

Comment: 1) Есть ли вообще по тому пути, что вы указываете, файл БД? 2) Покажите весь код, что выдает исключение, полностью, просто скопируйте его и в вопрос добавьте 3) Вы успеваете соединение открыть? 4) [похожий вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33282511/312041)

Comment: @tym32167 1) Файл есть 2) Код добавил в вопрос 3) Ошибка происходит ещё до соединения - вылавливаю при отладке 4) Прописал рекомендуемый код - Ошибка всё равно остается

Comment: Сам LocalDB установлен?

Comment: Расшарьте файл бд где нибудь, если там ничего важного нет, я попробую со своего компа

Comment: @tym32167 после строки: connect1.Open(); проверяю значение connect1 в ней ServerVersion теперь принимает значение 13.00.4001. Видимо после метода Open ошибка исчезает.

Comment: Забудьте на время про свойство ServerVersion и "ошибку до соединения". Покажите реальный код (который что-то делает, а не просто создает объект SqlConnection) и вывод Exception.ToString().

Answer (score 1):

Откроем Visual Studio, там есть Server Explorer, добавим ему подключение

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В подключении укажем файл БД, которого ещё нет

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Студия спросит о создании файла, создаём

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

в Server Explorer начнем добавление таблицы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Таблицу сформируем простенькую, Id-Name

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SampleTable] 
(
    [Id]   INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY ,
    [Name] NVARCHAR (50) NULL
);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Начнем выполнение скрипта для создания таблицы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Обновим список таблиц в БД

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нам нужна конкретная таблица

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Добавим в неё немного данных

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Дальше, смотрим свойства БД

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В свойствах нас интересует строка соединения

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Копируем её и вставляем в наш код для получения данных

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сам код

```
 string conStr = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=D:\Code\github\SO_Samples\src\RU_985418\DB\MyDatabaseSample.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30";
 using (var connection = new SqlConnection(conStr))
 {
     connection.Open();
     var command = new SqlCommand("SELECT [Id], [Name] FROM [SampleTable]", connection);
     var reader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync();

     while (reader.Read())
     {
         Console.WriteLine($"ID: {reader.GetInt32(0)}, Name: {reader.GetString(1)}");
     }
 }
```

Строка подключения получилась такая

```
Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=D:\Code\github\SO_Samples\src\RU_985418\DB\MyDatabaseSample.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30
```

Весь исхордный код доступен [тут](https://github.com/tym32167/SO_Samples/blob/master/src/RU_985418/Program.cs), использовалась студия 2019.

Пробуйте этот сценарий, смотрите где у вас будет затык.