# Вывести Объекты класса ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core

Создал по шаблонам простое RestApi приложение,у меня есть классы User и Award и их контексты соответственно, объекты класса User я легко вывожу на хост, а при выводе объектов Award возникает ошибка, показанная на скриншоте, буду очень благодарен за помощь и подсказку.

Startup:

```
 public class Startup
{

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        AwardsContext ac;
        string con1 = "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=usersdbstore;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true";
        string con2 = "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=awardsdbstore;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true";
        //AwardsContext.Database.EnsureCreated();
        services.AddDbContext<UsersContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(con1));
        services.AddDbContext<AwardsContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(con2));
        services.AddMvc();

    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseMvc();
    }
}
```

AwardsContext:

```
public class AwardsContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Award> Awards { get; set; }
        public AwardsContext(DbContextOptions<AwardsContext> options)
            : base(options)
        { }
    }
```

AwardsController:

```
public class AwardsController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly AwardsContext _contextAward;

    public AwardsController(AwardsContext contextAward)
    {
        _contextAward = contextAward;
        if(!_contextAward.Awards.Any())
        {
            _contextAward.Awards.Add(new Award() { Title = "Emmy", Description = "Американская телевизионная премия" });
            _contextAward.Awards.Add(new Award() { Title = "Grammy", Description = "Музыкальная премия Американской академии звукозаписи" });
            _contextAward.Awards.Add(new Award() { Title = "Oskar", Description = "Премия Американской академии кинематографических искусств и наук" });
            _contextAward.Awards.Add(new Award() { Title = "Tony", Description = "Театральная премия" });
            _contextAward.Awards.Add(new Award() { Title = "Премия Дарвина", Description = "Неофициальная премия, присуждаемая комиссией людям лишившим себя наследства по своей глупости и неосторожности" });
            _contextAward.SaveChanges();
        }
    }

    // GET: api/Awards
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<Award> GetAwards()
    {
        return _contextAward.Awards;
    }

    // GET: api/Awards/5
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetAward([FromRoute] int id)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        var award = await _contextAward.Awards.FindAsync(id);

        if (award == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Ok(award);
    }

    // PUT: api/Awards/5
    [HttpPut("{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PutAward([FromRoute] int id, [FromBody] Award award)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        if (id != award.Id)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        _contextAward.Entry(award).State = EntityState.Modified;

        try
        {
            await _contextAward.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {
            if (!AwardExists(id))
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        return NoContent();
    }

    // POST: api/Awards
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PostAward([FromBody] Award award)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        _contextAward.Awards.Add(award);
        await _contextAward.SaveChangesAsync();

        return CreatedAtAction("GetAward", new { id = award.Id }, award);
    }

    // DELETE: api/Awards/5
    [HttpDelete("{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteAward([FromRoute] int id)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        var award = await _contextAward.Awards.FindAsync(id);
        if (award == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        _contextAward.Awards.Remove(award);
        await _contextAward.SaveChangesAsync();

        return Ok(award);
    }

    private bool AwardExists(int id)
    {
        return _contextAward.Awards.Any(e => e.Id == id);
    }
}
```

[image: Вывод Users (все нормально)]

[image: Ошибка при выводе Awards]

Есть еще вариант ошибки, при коде :

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        //AwardsContext ac;
        string con1 = "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=usersdbstore;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true";
       // string con2 = "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=awardsdbstore;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true";
        //AwardsContext.Database.EnsureCreated();
        services.AddDbContext<UsersContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(con1));
        services.AddDbContext<AwardsContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(con1));
        services.AddMvc();

    }
```

Появляется ошибка:
[image: ошибка]

Comment: Нет скриншота с ошибкой

Comment: Извиняюсь, теперь есть

Comment: так у вас ошибка на скрине написана

Comment: Спасибо, я вижу, я спрашиваю как её исправить

Comment: очевидно, указать правильную строку соединения

Comment: Например? Я делал по гайду : https://metanit.com/sharp/aspnet5/23.2.php , где строка для users написана заранее, я её просто скопирую, какой она будет для awards?

Comment: так это ваша база, вам лучше знать, как к ней подключаться

Comment: вот [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/985818/179763) не совсем то, что у вас, но вы по аналогии можете подключиться к своей БД через студию и потом скопировать строку соединения

Answer (score 0, accepted):

appsettings.json

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "MyDatabase": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=usersdbstore;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true";
  },
}
```

startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<AwardsContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyDatabase")));
}
```